# Creating 2 dimensional array from larger 2 dimensional array

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get around the below problem and any help would be greatly appreciated

I have a 2 dimensional array that looks like the below;

[PFAllArr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJg1G.png)

I want to create a new array (PFArr) from this, but without the rows where deleted = "yes". I could make this new array the same size as the original one, just leaving blank rows where i have removed data, but this array will be used in numerous loops down the code so i want to make it as compact as possible.

With the below code i have tried to get the number of elements where deleted = 0 ( which i want to keep)... using a loop.

Then redim the new array to this size.

Then it should assign the relevant elements from the old array to the new array with the second loop. However it is not assigning the elements into the array as expected, it seems to be looping through fine, just not adding the new elements in. Any ideas?

```
Sub AddSelectDataFromBigArrayToSmallOne()

Dim PFAllArr As Variant
Dim PFArr As Variant
Dim c1, i1, c2, i2 As Long

PFAllArr = Sheets("PF File Simple").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value

'get number of elements i want to transfer to new array
c1 = 1
For i1 = LBound(PFAllArr) To UBound(PFAllArr)
    If PFAllArr(i1, 2) = 0 Then
    c1 = c1 + 1
    End If
Next i1

'Make new array this size
ReDim PFArr(LBound(PFAllArr) To c1, 1 To 4)

'Assign elements from old array nto new one
c2 = 1
For i2 = LBound(PFAllArr) To UBound(PFAllArr)
    If PFAllArr(i2, 2) = 0 Then
    PFArr(c2, 3) = PFAllArr(i2, 3)
    PFArr(c2, 4) = PFAllArr(i2, 4)
    c2 = c2 + 1
    End If
    Debug.Print c2, PFArr(c2, 3), PFArr(c2, 4)
Next i2

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to start with `c1` equal to 0

Comment: That did it urdearboy - thank you very much!

Comment: You have 3 solutions below. You should accept one of them to give credit to people that donate their time to help others :)

Comment: Ah i see. I did not know this. I thought the number of up votes decided that. Thanks again

Comment: Ah i see. I did not know this. I thought the number of up votes decided that. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim aTemp As Variant
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim iyTemp As Long
    Dim iyData As Long
    Dim ix As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PF File Simple").Range("A2").CurrentRegion
        aTemp = .Value
        ReDim aData(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1), 0), 1 To .Columns.Count)
    End With

    For iyTemp = 1 To UBound(aTemp, 1)
        If aTemp(iyTemp, 2) = 0 Then
            iyData = iyData + 1
            For ix = 1 To UBound(aTemp, 2)
                aData(iyData, ix) = aTemp(iyTemp, ix)
            Next ix
        End If
    Next iyTemp

    'aData is now populated with only values where the second column is 0

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks a lot slicker than my code tigeravatar thanks! I got mine working with with urdearboys suggestion above. I can see that your way is more efficient though, will use that in the future

Answer (score 3):

### Two things

1. You will need to change `c1` to start at **0** instead of **1**. If you declare your variable type right, you can just not set the initial value. `Long` type variable will default to **0** unless stated otherwise
2. Your variable block `Dim c1, i1, c2, i2 As Long` is  not working how you may think it is. You are actually declaring `i2` as `Long` and the rest of your variables are being pushed into `Variant` type variable. This part is less important, but chives well on this topic: you can also just use `Dim PFAllArr, PFArr` and these will default to `Variant`

---

Thus, you can start your code like so (removed your `c1` set, and updated lines to declare variables as intended):

```
Sub AddSelectDataFromBigArrayToSmallOne()

Dim PFAllArr, PFArr
Dim c1 as Long, i1 as Long, c2 as Long, i2 As Long

PFAllArr = Sheets("PF File Simple").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value

For i1 = LBound(PFAllArr) To UBound(PFAllArr)
    If PFAllArr(i1, 2) = 0 Then
    c1 = c1 + 1
    End If
Next i1
```

*IMO, @tigeravatar's solution looks cleaner. Regardless of which code you end up using, it is always nice to see why yours didn't work*

Comment: Great explanation for the issue OP encountered and how to correct it, +1

Comment: Fine explanation +1, maybe interested in my approach,too.

Comment: Yes that is definitely true regarding finding out why your own code isn't working. I learned a lot from fixing that and it would have been wrecking my head for weeks if i didn't fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Application.Index`**

You can use the advanced filtering possibilities of the `Index` function:

**Main procedure**

```
Sub DelRows()
  Dim PFAllArr, PFArr
' [1a] create 2-dim data field array (1-based)
  PFAllArr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PF File Simple").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2
' [1b] filter out rows to be deleted
  PFArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(PFAllArr, getAr(PFAllArr, 2), Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(PFAllArr, 2) & ")")))
End Sub
```

**Helper function getAr()**

```
Function getAr(v, ByVal colNo&) As Variant()
' Purpose: collect row numbers not to be deleted (criteria <> "YES" in 2nd column)
' Note:    called by above procedure DelRows
  Dim ar, i&, n&
  ReDim ar(0 To UBound(v) - 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
      If UCase$(v(i, colNo)) <> "YES" Then
         ar(n) = i: n = n + 1
      End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve ar(0 To n - 1): getAr = ar
End Function
```